# MySql in pivotal cloud foundry environment

Tags: mysql, paas, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

Does MySql come out of the box installed in pivotal cloud foundry environment? I was told that the containers within cloud foundry are transient in nature. If so , how does it support MySQL DB installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivotal offers Cloud Foundry in a couple ways.  The hosted service is called [Pivotal Web Services](https://run.pivotal.io) and allows apps to bind to a MySQL service such as ClearDB -- check out the [marketplace](https://console.run.pivotal.io/marketplace).

The on-premise offering of Pivotal Cloud Foundry provides a [MySQL service](https://network.pivotal.io/products/p-mysql) as well.

MySQL itself doesn't run as an application on Cloud Foundry, it's offered as a service alongside Cloud Foundry.  Cloud Foundry currently only runs stateless applications, but support for a cloud-native solution for [persistent workloads is starting up](https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/archives/list/cf-dev@lists.cloudfoundry.org/message/DFJJ6VGRZOSF4U4SVA6BDATAAJ7F3HHN/), so in the future it would be possible to run MySQL as an "application" directly on Cloud Foundry.

Comment: Thanks Amit! Does the service just implement service broker interface and probably help in externalizing the connection parameters and provide support for connection pools ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question.  I didn't mention service brokers, but I guess you dug around a bit and came across them.  Your question is what the purpose of the service broker is?

Comment: Hi Amit , I've been using cloud foundry for the past 2-3 months and have come across user defined and managed services. My understanding was that in case of managed services come along with the required implementing if service broker and in case of user defined services , the one who is defining the service has to take care of the implementation. When you referred to MySQL service , I assume you were taking about managed service. I wanted to understand what is the advantage of using this over defining the connection details within the application ( or externalizing it in property files )

Comment: That's a good question, but maybe it deserves its own separate question, rather than shoving too much into this comments section?

Comment: Sure Amit , will create a new question. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Amit , Can you please help with this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759332/pivotal-cloud-foundry-managed-vs-user-defined-service